# Pytorch compute separate losses of stacked tensors

Tags: python, machine-learning, torch

I have a `(N, k, 1)` tensor resulting from stacking scalar predictions of `k` networks. `N` is the batch size.

The target for all the predictions is the same, `t`. How can I compute the loss (e.g. MSE) efficiently? What I am doing now is splitting the predictions for each network and summing the separate losses.

```py
stacked_predictions  # (N, k, 1) tensor with the predictions
t  # common target

predictions = [prediction[:, i] for i in range(stacked_predictions.size()[1])]
loss = sum(self.loss(prediciton, t) for prediction in predictions)

optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Is there a more efficient way of achieving the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thankfully you can do it in python easily with broadcasting:
Assuming:

```
N=100 #For example
k=10 #For example
stacked_predictions = torch.randn(N, k, 1)  # (N, k, 1) tensor with the predictions
t = torch.randn(N,1)  # common target
```

Then, you can get an efficient equivalent computation of `loss`:

```
loss = k * nn.MSELoss()(stacked_predictions, t[:, None, :])
```

(Replace nn.MSELoss() with `self.loss` in your case).
Notice that `t[:, None, :]` adds another singleton dimension to `t` at the middle, so `t` become of shape `(N,1,1)` while `stacked_predictions` is of shape `(N,k,1)`. When you call `nn.MSELoss()` on these 2 tensors, deep inside `t` will be broadcasted to match `stacked_predictions`'s shape and this is what saves you the need to repeat `t` yourself.

Notice that I added multiplication by `k`, that is because you wanted the sum and not the mean over dimension 1 (the one with size `k`). omit the multiplication in case you want the mean over all predictions.

Comment: My pleasure, Federico :)